# CSS large square grid - how to generate a table

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to make a grid of around 50 columns and 50 rows with height and width of each cell to be 10px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
 {
   border-collapse:collapse;
 }
table,th, td
 {
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
td{width:10px;}
tr{height:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I can do this by writing the code a hundred times..
But I think there should be some more practical way of doing this by css..
Can anyone help...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do it in css, but you can certainly do it with javascript:

```
<style>
    td {
        width: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    tr {
        height: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function makeCells() {
        var t = document.createElement("TABLE");

        for (var rows = 0; rows < 50; rows++) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("TR");
            console.log(newRow);
            t.appendChild(newRow);
            for (var cols = 0; cols < 50; cols++) {
                var newCell = document.createElement("TD");
                newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(t);
    }

    makeCells();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
td {
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
```

However, using a table you can't be sure the width will be always 10px for each cell, because if the window's width is less than the table width, the cells will shrink by default.

Comment: but how to generate a numerous number of such elements.. I mean a 50x50 grid

Comment: You can't generate new markup with CSS. Copy-paste is the way, or use the [emmet plugin](http://docs.emmet.io/) for your text editor if you want to be faster.

Comment: i.e. this emmet snippet will generate a 50x50 table: `table>tr*50>td*50`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
       table{ border-collapse:collapse; }
       table,th, td{ border: 1px solid black; }
       td{width:10px;}
       tr{height:10px;}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table border="1">
   <?php for($ctr=0; $ctr<=50; $ctr++){ ?>
   <tr>
       <?php for($ctr2=0; $ctr2<=50; $ctr2++){ ?>
       <td></td>
       <?php }?>
   </tr>
   <?php }?>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```

just a try

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other, working answers, you could try something like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/x9MaJ/2/)

What I've done is created 2500 `<div>`s with javascript, then gave them a padding of 1% in a 500px container. 1% of 500 is 5, so that gives us the 10px by 10px square. Float them all left in the container and they nicely align into this 50x50 grid.

The key code is:

```
div {
    padding: 1%;
    background: #aaa;
    float: left;
}
```

I added alternate background colours to help show you what is there.
This won't play very nicely if you add content to the divs, but it looks like you aren't wanting to do that anyway if they are just 10px wide.

Answer (score 0):

You need 50 × 50 elements anyway, and you cannot create elements in a loop in CSS or in HTML (they have no loops, as they are not programming languages). There are many different ways to generate the elements in server-side or client-side programming languages, but you first need to decide which technology to use and then use the elementary constructs of the chosen language.